# How to export the table of a database in a container using a bash script?

Tags: python, mysql, docker

I want to export a table from a database in a container `8beb34269697`, here is my procedure

```
$ docker exec -it 8beb34269697 bash
root@8beb34269697:/# mysqldump -u user -h localhost -p password database_name table_name > table.sql
Enter password:
root@8beb34269697:/# exit
exit
$ docker cp 8beb34269697:/table.sql .
```

I want to write a bash script `run.sh`, every time I run `./run.sh` on local machine, then ta-da, `table.sql` is produced. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should look up volume mounting in docker. Then you can mount a volume where you want your output to go.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a research of this method.

Comment: You should be able to run `mysqldump` directly from the host, without having to involve Docker at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run `mysqldump` command without having to enter in the container in two steps:

```
docker exec -ti 8beb34269697 /usr/bin/mysqldump -u user -h localhost -ppassword database_name table_name > table.sql
```

EDIT: changed from `-p password` to `-ppassword` because in the first case the string "password" will be taken as the database name instead of the password itself.

Comment: fantastic, a little problem, it seems I need to press `return` manually afterward, then it can be done, how I simulate this action.